# Determine if a JSON file has been downloaded correctly?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova

A very simple question, how to I determine if a **JSON** file has been downloaded correctly? I am connecting and getting the file from the API using ajax.

Thanks.

Let me show the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function(uri){
        writeFile(name, JSON.stringify(uri), "Inmark/InmarkDictionary");
        ISAPP.spinner.hide();
    }, 
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
       if(status == "timeout") {
           ErrorAlert(label.requestTimeoutLabel);
       } else {
           ErrorAlert('URL : ' + error.message + ' | status: ' + status);
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure, but you can try to parse it and verify successful parsing happened or not. `JSON.parse()`

Comment: If you are receiving a 200 response code (the done handler on ajax) and you can parse the data coming back as JSON then you can be satisfied the json is correct.

Comment: Mostly this is not a problem. If you think you're likely to have trouble then you could create a checksum with SHA256, MD5, whatever, and send that along with the file and check it after the transfer is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `done()` or `success()` to know if transfer is complete:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "example.php"
}).done(function() {
  alert( "success" );
});
```

and then check with JSON parse:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "example.php"
}).success(function() {
  try {
    parsedData = JSON.parse(response);
  } catch (e) {
    // is not a valid JSON string
  }
});
```

Comment: @Nothing Since you have improved your answer I have now removed my comment. Your comment, however, I have flagged as not constructive

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, if its a simple JSON file or any other format your application wont know its downloaded correctly or not unless the downloaded file/script runs and/or communicate to it or you make your application look for it (something like File.exist).

However in order to make JSON download available, you may find this helpful:
http://jsfiddle.net/cowboy/hHZa9/

```
var obj = {a: 123, b: "4 5 6"};
var data = "text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj));

$('<a href="data:' + data + '" download="data.json">download JSON</a>').appendTo('#container');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If the status code of the ajax request is 200, it means the download job is done as expected.
2. If you want to make sure the content of the JSON Object is 100% correct, you can sign the content (To be simple, MD5/SHA is good enough; if you want to be more secure, you can use RSA or EC). For example, the remote server calculate the signature, and put it in JSON :

   json : {
   content : {
        //put your origional JSON here
   },
   signature : "13241234123412342134"
   }

   After browser gets the JSON object, re-check the signature to validate the content.
3. Or you can use HTTPS. The browser will do validation for you.

Comment: How do I sign it if I don't have access to the API? the app only fetches the JSON file.

Comment: I am afraid you must be able to access the server code (To do signature, both server and client/browser code needs to be changed).

Comment: If you cannot, I think using HTTPS is the simplest way. HTTPS protocol makes sure the security, integrity of data between server and browser.

Comment: when i made it HTTPS i started having problem connecting to the API.

Comment: Please make sure the remote API supports HTTPS protocol.